# Replace yaml config with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following yaml file called file.yaml

```
# This is a file store

  - file-store:
      version: 2
      enabled: no

  - file-store2:
      version: 4
      enabled: yes
```

Is there a way to enable the file-store option for the first group?. I tried to use this one but it doesn't work:

```
sed -i '/^ *file-store:/,/^ *[^:]*:/s/enabled: no/enabled: yes/' file.yaml
```

Expected output:

```
  # This is a file store

  - file-store:
      version: 2
      enabled: yes

  - file-store2:
      version: 4
      enabled: yes
```

Comment: Could you use a proper YAML syntax aware parser like `yq`? `sed` is line oriented and does not understand YAML grammar

Comment: Thanks.. I just learn something new about yq.. I will learn to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the recommendations given by @HatLess you can try to use this pure `sed` solution. I know, it's too wordy but it's more reliable even though not 100%.

```
# Capture the block between "- file-store:" and "- file store.*:"
/^[ ]*- file-store:/,/^[ ]*- file-store[^:]*:/ {
    # Look for te string having "enabled:"
    # and replace the last non-whitespace sequence with "yes"
    /enabled:/ s/[^ ][^ ]*$/yes/
}
```

and the short inline version of the script:

```
sed '/^[ ]*- file-store:/,/^[ ]*- file-store[^:]*:/ { /enabled:/ s/[^ ][^ ]*$/yes/ }'
```

Comment: This is a working pure sed. Thanks. I was having difficult to use yq when the file has `dash` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yq`

```
$ cat file
  file1:
      version: 2
      enabled: no

   file2:
      version: 4
      enabled: yes
```

To change the value of enabled, use:

```
$ yq -e '.file1.enabled = "yes"' file
{
  "file1": {
    "version": 2,
    "enabled": "yes"
  },
  "file2": {
    "version": 4,
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

To save in place, add `-yi` flag

As your question includes `sed`, here is a fragile solution

```
$ sed '/file1/ {n;N;s/no/yes/}' file
   file1:
      version: 2
      enabled: yes

   file2:
      version: 4
      enabled: yes
```

Comment: I'm not sure why did you change all the input without the dash symbol.. it does not work.

Comment: I wish to see example when u have dash input like I showed to u. Pretty new to yq.